# create site Collection from site template containing blog subsite sp2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection

I want to create a site collection based on a `site template` that contains a `calendar app` and a `blog` subsite.

I explain, i have a site that contains a subsite of type `blog` site and also contains a calendar in `sharepoint 2013`, i saved the site as a template and checked **`include content`**.

However,
when i create a new sitecollection based on that template, i get the calendar app but never the blog subsite...

Am i missing something here? And how can we do this please?

Comment: what is base template of your site collection?

Comment: @ Waqas Sarwar MCSE Team site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

site templates do not include subsites

you may want to create a separate template containing the blog as well

[Trying to create a template with subsites](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110254/trying-to-create-a-template-with-subsites/110261#110261)